# Symlinks creation to sprkl binaries at /usr/local/bin failed

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Ran into this arror trying an install this extension on WSL.
Any idea on how this can be resolved? I have tried editing and adding PATH Variables.

```
:~$ npx @sprkl/scripts install
 Starting sprkl installation!
    Installation path: "/home/isaac/.sprkl"
 Verifying dependencies(operating system, node and docker)
✅ Sprkl support OS Linux
✅ Supported node version was found!
    Node version: "v18.9.1"
[Docker] Check docker existence and accessibility
    command: "docker ps"
✅ Docker is installed and accessible
⚡ Installing npm packages under=/home/isaac/.sprkl/lib
Installing...
✅ NPM packages installed successfully

❌ Sprkl installation failed.
Reason: Symlinks creation to sprkl binaries at /usr/local/bin failed.
Suggestion: Please edit the PATH and SPRKL_PREFIX envars
(for unix systems usually in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc):
export SPRKL_PREFIX="/home/isaac/.sprkl"
export PATH="$PATH:$SPRKL_PREFIX/bin"
Try resolving the issue, or contact the sprkl team.
Then run install again to complete installation:
npx @sprkl/scripts install
For further information: /home/isaac/.sprkl/installation_logs/installation-log1664001104848.log
```

Comment: If you didn't run this with `sudo`, `npx` will not have permissions to install symlinks. Probably just live without them, and restart your shell after following the instructions in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

To access the path **`/usr/local/bin`**. You need to have **`root`** permission. And also need to create a **`Symlinks`** you need to have **`root`** permission.

So try to run that command as **`sudo`**.

```bash
sudo npx @sprkl/scripts install
```

Comment: ```$ sudo npx @sprkl/scripts@0.0.43 install
[sudo] password for isaac:
sudo: npx: command not found ```  This happens when I try the command with sudo

Comment: @IsaacTonyloi Your node js isn't installed globally. Maybe you have installed `node.js` locally for only the user `isaac`. In order to use `nodejs` as `sudo` you need to install it globally